# How to solve POSTGRESQL SCRAM authentication problem while connecting with QGIS

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos7, qgis

Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above.
i have tried to install /upgrade libpq which is not supporting on CENTOS (7.9 )
also tried to reinstall qgis(yum install qgis).I am getting an error after the installation QGIS
below are the details:

```
[root@localhost ~]# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.8

[root@localhost ~]# gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@localhost ~]# qgis --version
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
Warning: QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /root/.qgis2//project_templates
(QGIS VERSION 2.14.9)
```

Comment: QGIS 2.x is outdated. Try with a recent version (latest LTR is 3.28)

Comment: How did you install in the first place?  Did you configure some non-default repository?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a modern PostgreSQL accept MD5-encrypted passwords you need to:

- set the authentication method in `pg_hba.conf` to `md5`
- set the default password encryption to MD5 by setting `password_encryption = 'scram-sha-256'` in `postgresql.conf`
- if you have users with a SCRAM encrypted password you need to reset their password so they get MD5 encrypted passwords

Take a look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html) which describes the inverse process of upgrading an old Postgres-configuration to use the modern SCRAM encryption:

> To upgrade an existing installation from md5 to scram-sha-256, after having ensured that all client libraries in use are new enough to support SCRAM, set password_encryption = 'scram-sha-256' in postgresql.conf, make all users set new passwords, and change the authentication method specifications in pg_hba.conf to scram-sha-256.

Be aware that [MD5 is not considered secure any more](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19908). So I would suggest you plan for an update of QGIS that uses a more recent PostgreSQL client library supporting SCRAM.

Comment: That last link is pretty useless here.  They can't do an offline attack on the hash value unless they already have the hash value which is stored on the server.  And if they do have the hash value that is stored on the server, they can just play "pass the hash" so they don't need to break it.  (Which itself is a security weakness, but is not the weakness which that link describes)

Comment: @jjanes If you only consider hacking into PostgreSQL yes, I agree, that can be done by passing the hash, no need for the clear text password. But we all know people tend to reuse passwords more than they should. And therefore it is dangerous to encrypt passwords using weak encryption because an attacker who steals the hash can calculate the password from it and use it on other services.